# How to move one directory to another one when they are not in the same level of Hierarchy in GitHub

Tags: git, github

In my git repository I have a folder in directory :

> src/main/Protocol/Game

Now i want to remove this Game folder in directory :

> src/main/SecondProtocol

Since from what I know is that when we use:

> git mv Game SecondProtocol

it is not going to work since we are not in the same level of the directories.

I use the above command when i am in Game directory and because of that above command is not working.

If somebody can help me I will really appreciate

Comment: Why don't you just move the directory without git?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That would lose version history.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `..` to specify a parent directory

```
cd src/main/Protocol && git mv Game ../SecondProtocol
```

**or**

```
cd src/main/SecondProtocol && git mv ../Game .
```

*etc.*